# How to remove % sign from loyalty points column in nosql where every values is like 2%,3%

Tags: json, nosql

I have values for each product bought by customer of loyalty points earned as 2%,3%.I want to remove % sign only from this as I want to further assign badges earned on the basis of sum of points for each customer.It has to be done in no sql Json format.

The points are in the below format as shown:

"Loyalty_Points___": "2%",
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "5cf6f5644c587d668bab6111"

I want to remove % sign only from this as I want to further assign badges earned on the basis of sum of points for each customer

Answer (score 0):

Use the code like this : 
Loyalty_Points: {$replaceAll: ["$Loyalty_Points", "%", ""]}

and then use $toInt to convert this field into an integer for further calculations.